# C# Start Process on Mac - FFMPEG - Exit Code 1

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, process, ffmpeg

I am trying to start a process on Mac and Windows (using Unity) to run FFMPEG to convert a video to a .ogv video. My code is as follows:

```
    string command = "ffmpeg -i '" + filepath + "'  -codec:v libtheora -qscale:v 10 -codec:a libvorbis -qscale:a 10 -y '"+workingDir+"/ogv_Video/"+System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath)+".ogv'";
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Command: "+command);

    try{

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo (workingDir+"/..", command);
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName =workingDir+"/ffmpeg";

        //Process.Start (startInfo);
        Process p = Process.Start(startInfo); 
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        string strOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); 
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("Running..."+strOutput);
        p.WaitForExit(); 

        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("Got here. "+strOutput);
        int exitCode = p.ExitCode;
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("Process exit code = "+exitCode);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("An error occurred");
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("Error: "+e);
    }
```

The command executes and does not through any exception. However, it terminates instantly and prints **Exit Code 1** which is "Catchall for general errors" -this seems not too helpful!

What am I doing wrong with my code, please?

You'll notice that my code prints out the command in full. If I copy that command and paste it into the terminal, it runs absolutely fine.

Comment: This might help http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/161444/how-to-use-processstart-with-arguments-on-osx-in-a.html

Comment: @Takarii Thank you for your comment - unfortunately I am already doing this with the line `startInfo.FileName =workingDir+"/ffmpeg";` I have a copy of FFMPEG stored in the working directory of the project (and ultimately the build) so that I can guarantee where it is located. I have also tried just referencing ffmpeg without a path name before it, but that didn't work either

Comment: I see.  I'm not well versed in unity, but c# is my area. I know that if you use the `system.diagnostics.process.start()` method can be used in osx, but you need to use an absolute path to a program or file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was setting up the arguments wrongly. Referring to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922175/ffmpeg-run-from-shell-runs-properly-but-does-not-when-called-from-within-net), I was able to produce the expected result with the following code:

```
try{

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) +@"ffmpeg";

        process.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();


        JSONDataObject rtnMsg = new JSONDataObject("StartConvertOK", "-1", new List<string>());
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(rtnMsg);

    }
```

It does seem as though the answer was not that different from what I was doing, but it does work!