# Passing arguments to Terminal on Mac via C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm having some trouble passing arguments to a terminal via visual studio in C#.

I can successfully open the terminal, but the arguments I pass seem to be ignored.

General Info:

- Visual Studio for Mac version 8.9 build 1651
- Solution = Cocoa app
- Using Xamarin/Xcode
- Terminal command works fine when I open a terminal and type it myself

Here's my code:

```cs
var encode = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
encode.StartInfo.FileName = ("/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal");
encode.StartInfo.Arguments = ("ffmpeg -i " + filepath + " -acodec copy file_fixed.mp3");
encode.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
encode.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

encode.Start();
```

As stated, the terminal opens fine, but doesn't do anything with the args I send to it.

Things I've tried:

- Setting RedirectsStandardInput = true and then manually sending the commands, but it never responds.
- Adding /c, -c, and every permutation thereof to my arguments.

Comment: Why do you need to open the Terminal app in order to fun ffmpeg?

Comment: @Jason because the ffmpeg package doesn't work with xamarin. I've tried it every single way I can. This is the only way I can use ffmpeg.

Comment: no, I'm asking why you think Terminal is part of the solution.  Terminal doesn't run any commands, the shell (zsh, bsh, etc) does.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174612/c-sharp-start-process-on-mac-ffmpeg-exit-code-1

Comment: @Jason if I understand correctly, the solution should be to include a version of ffmpeg in the working directory of the solution, and then invoking that ffmpeg file with my arguments to operate on my file. I've been working all day, so I'll attempt this tomorrow and let you know if it works out. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @Jason no luck. I've added ffmpeg to the resources folder of my solution, and then called it as a process with the same args as above. Nothing happens.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+mac+run+shell+script+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jason I'm very new to coding so please excuse my ignorance. Are you suggesting that I create a shell script in my res folder that runs the ffmpeg commands?

Comment: no, just call the ffmpeg executable.  Generally scripts/executables are interchangeable in this context.  The point is that there are dozens of existing questions that explain how to do this.

Comment: That's what I tried to do:
Added ffmpeg to my resources folder, called it via sys.diag.proc.start() with args. Nothing happened.

Comment: why are you adding it to your resources folder?  Just use the path to the ffmpeg executable

Comment: Used the path to the exe. Nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I found. It may not be the best, but it works.

1. Create a bash script that contains the code you want the terminal to perform and have it take the args you specify.
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31414/how-can-i-pass-a-command-line-argument-into-a-shell-script.

(You can make one on MacOS by creating a text file and saving as yourfile.exe and then running chmod +x yourfile.exe from terminal to enable it.)

2. Place your file in the resources folder in your solution. (Right-click resources in solution explorer -> add -> existing files.
3. Reference this file by using this code:

```
string bashpath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/yourfile.exe";
string args = "your args here";

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

proc.StartInfo.FileName = bashpath;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
proc.Start();
```

Things to remember:

- Your resources folder will be **inside** your .app file. Right-click->show package contents.
- Add `Exit 0`  to the end of your script so you can call proc.WaitForExit();